# Woocommerce: I want to make the shopping cart drop down after add to cart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have been trying to do something rather simple: getting a cart to dropdown after a user added something to their cart and stay there, until they click it away.

I've tried adding a php function through functions.php in my childtheme, adding custom javascript code, but it doesn't react. I can't seem to capture the event with javascript/jquery.
Woocommerce reloads the page after adding something to the cart, since it's a variation product.

This is what the html code for the cart looks like:

```
<div id="shoppingcart-dropdown" class="mkd-shopping-cart-dropdown">
                            <ul>
                                                                    <li>
                                        <div class="mkd-item-image-holder">
                                            <a itemprop="url" href="https://gemini-bracelets.com/collection/ladies/musthave-deluxe-vanilla-8mm/">
                                                <img src="//gemini-bracelets.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Musthave-Deluxe-Summer-Night-8mm-300x200.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail size-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" width="300" height="200">                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mkd-item-info-holder">
                                            <h5 itemprop="name" class="mkd-product-title"><a itemprop="url" href="https://gemini-bracelets.com/collection/ladies/musthave-deluxe-vanilla-8mm/">Musthave Deluxe Summer Night 8mm</a></h5>
                                            <span class="mkd-quantity">2</span>
                                            <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>39,95</span>                                            <a href="https://gemini-bracelets.com/cart/?remove_item=6c2e0a0990dacd72f16b437da82dc6cc&amp;_wpnonce=663fbc7a93" class="remove" title="Remove this item"><span class="icon-arrows-remove"></span></a>                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                                                    <li>
                                        <div class="mkd-item-image-holder">
                                            <a itemprop="url" href="https://gemini-bracelets.com/collection/ladies/musthave-deluxe-vanilla-8mm/">
                                                <img src="//gemini-bracelets.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Musthave-Deluxe-Summer-Night-8mm-300x200.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail size-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" width="300" height="200">                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mkd-item-info-holder">
                                            <h5 itemprop="name" class="mkd-product-title"><a itemprop="url" href="https://gemini-bracelets.com/collection/ladies/musthave-deluxe-vanilla-8mm/">Musthave Deluxe Summer Night 8mm</a></h5>
                                            <span class="mkd-quantity">3</span>
                                            <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>39,95</span>                                            <a href="https://gemini-bracelets.com/cart/?remove_item=8ed888de28bd08234d727d879e5f7a36&amp;_wpnonce=663fbc7a93" class="remove" title="Remove this item"><span class="icon-arrows-remove"></span></a>                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                                                <div class="mkd-cart-bottom">
                                    <div class="mkd-subtotal-holder clearfix">
                                        <span class="mkd-total">TOTAL:</span>
                                        <span class="mkd-total-amount">
                                        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>199,75</span>                                  </span>
                                    </div>
                                                                        <div class="mkd-btn-holder clearfix">
                                        <a itemprop="url" href="https://gemini-bracelets.com/cart/" class="mkd-view-cart" data-title="VIEW CART"><span>VIEW CART</span></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mkd-btn-holder clearfix">
                                        <a itemprop="url" href="https://gemini-bracelets.com/checkout/" class="mkd-view-cart" data-title="CHECKOUT"><span>CHECKOUT</span></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

And this is what I have been trying to do with jquery:

```
window.jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
    $( 'body' ).on( 'added_to_cart', function ( event, fragments, cart_hash, $button ) {

        $('div#shoppingcart-dropdown').addClass('.after-add');
        $('body').on('click', function(){
            $('#shoppingcart-dropdown').removeClass('.after-add');
        })
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add yourself into cart using ajax. First you have to prevent the running default function and add the cart by putting below function.
This function in your script file.

```
$('.add_to_cart_button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var product_id = $(this).attr('data-product_id');

    $.post(ajaxhandle,{'action':'add_foobar','product_id':product_id},function(response){

        if(response==0){
        console.log('error');   
        }
      else{
            console.log('success');
        }
    });

});
```

This function in functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_foobar', 'prefix_ajax_add_foobar' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_foobar', 'prefix_ajax_add_foobar' );

function prefix_ajax_add_foobar() {
$product_id  = $_POST['product_id'];

// add code the add the product to your cart
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
die();
}
```

Bellow function create short code for Mini cart. You can put this[custom-mini-cart] shortcode wherever you want..

```
// you can change the display as per your wish
function custom_mini_cart() {
//don't want total means you can remove this
echo '<a href="#" class="dropdown-back" data-toggle="dropdown"> ';
    echo '<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    echo '<div class="basket-item-count" style="display: inline;">';
        echo '<span class="cart-items-count count">';
            echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
        echo ' items -'; 
        echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total();
        echo  '</span>';
    echo '</div>';
echo '</a>';
echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-mini-cart">';
        echo '<li> <div class="widget_shopping_cart_content">';
                  woocommerce_mini_cart();
            echo '</div></li></ul>';

}
add_shortcode( 'custom-mini-cart', 'custom_mini_cart' );
```

This function for automatically refresh the mini cart.

```
//you have to change according to above mini cart shortcode function.

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', function($fragments) {

ob_start();
?>

<a href="#" class="dropdown-back" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <div class="basket-item-count" style="display: inline;">
        <span class="cart-items-count count">
            <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?>
        items -
        <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?>
        </span>
    </div>
</a>

<?php $fragments['a.dropdown-back'] = ob_get_clean();

return $fragments;

} );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', function($fragments) {

ob_start();
?>

<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-mini-cart">
       <li> <div class="widget_shopping_cart_content">
                  <?php woocommerce_mini_cart(); ?>
            </div></li></ul>

<?php $fragments['ul.dropdown-menu'] = ob_get_clean();

return $fragments;

} );
```

please just try it..

Comment: I already have the code for the dropdown cart and it works correctly already on hover and click and so on, but now I want that existing cart to display after something has been added to cart. It should stay there untill the customer clicks away or closes the cart.

Comment: yes I understood, in first coding i wrote.it will give response when product is added. you can use that to display mini cart.then change the mini cart according to your wish. you can add whatever style and jquery for it..you can change the mini cart from hover display to whatever u needed..

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to target the specific moment after a successfull add to cart.
To the success.php file inside of the notices directory within the child-template woocoommerce folder, I added a script tag with my own javascript code.

success.php within notices directory in woocommerce:

```
<?php
/**
 * Show messages
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/notices/success.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

if ( ! $messages ) {
    return;
}

?>

<?php foreach ( $messages as $message ) : ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-message"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $message ); ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>

//here is where I added my jquery/javascript code and this time it does target everything correctly. 
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        //added specific hover class that I can remove the hover-css from.
        $("#cart-holder-div").removeClass("has-hover");

        //adding specific class so that I can add my own css. 
        $('#shoppingcart-dropdown').addClass("after-add-cart");

        //once the customer clicks anywhere, the removed and added classes are undone.
        $(document).click(function(){

            $("#cart-holder-div").addClass("has-hover");
            $('#shoppingcart-dropdown').removeClass("after-add-cart");
            $("#shoppingcart-dropdown").hide();
        });

        //to make sure the previous click event doesn't target the actual shopping cart
        $("#shoppingcart-dropdown").click(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
        });


    });
</script>
```